# how to send a 2d array javascript to sinatra

Tags: javascript, ruby, arrays, sinatra

I have a 2d array in javascript which I have to send to sinatra and store using datamapper,
I've been trying to put them in forms, but its a bit difficult to do it with forms, can I send an array to sinatra and process it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send it to Sinatra encoding the content as a JSON string and passing it using the body part of a POST request.

Here's how the string should look like.

```
require 'json'
JSON.dump([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
# => "[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]"
```

Send the content to Sinatra (using `curl` or any other HTTP library)

```
$ curl -d "[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]" http://localhost:3000/loader
```

Then instruct Sinatra to handle the path

```
post '/loader' do
  json = JSON.load(request.body.read)
  # ... do something with json
end
```

Note. I haven't tried the code actually, so you might need small changes to make it working. This is just a prototype.

Comment: thanks, putting together your answer and @raina77ow 's answer
JS/JQUERY:
`$.post("/save/sources",JSON.stringify(2darray),function(data){console.log(data)});`
RUBY:
`post '/save/sources' do
   json=JSON.load(request.body.read)
   json.each{|j|
                        }`